# Array.Copy error trying to convert single() to byte()

Tags: arrays, vb.net, type-conversion

I wanted to edit some audio / wave data with manipulation, I have read the audio data as single().

Now, after manipulation, I want to write it to a new audio file.
For this, I would like to write the singles() as bytes().

I am trying to convert the singles() to bytes(), but something always goes wrong.

I am currently trying

```
Public Overridable Overloads Sub Write(ByVal uSingles() As Single)

    Dim nBytes(uSingles.Length * 4) As Byte

    Array.Copy(uSingles, nBytes, uSingles.Length)

    (...)
```

But the Array.Copy always throws an error. 
Does anybody see my mistake?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it throws `TypeMismatchException` because there is difference in `srcArray` type and `destArray` type. In fact, this isn't about copying `single` array. I think you have to use `Stream` (`System.IO.MemoryStream`) in order to produce `byte()` array.

I suggest something like this:

```
Public Function Write(ByVal uSingles() As Single) As Byte()
  Using ms As New MemoryStream
         Using bw As New BinaryWriter(ms)
           For Each no In uSingles
              bw.Write(no)
           Next
        End Using
     Return ms.ToArray()
  End Using
End Function
```